# Segmention Fault on the while in reviews.csv

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc, strdup, strsep

> When i try run with the reviews.csv file the code gives segmention
> fault don't know why!!
>  Can someone HELP me with that...
>  In
> guião1v2.h only are the structs made for this.
>  In the code i add
> some comments for being much easier understand what i'm doing.
>
> I don't know how to fix this!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "guião1v2.h"

#define COUNT 1024
#define MAX_LINE 10000000 //random num (the files given are big)


int main(int arg , char*argv[]){
    
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[COUNT];
    char *buffer2 = malloc(COUNT);
    User *user = malloc(sizeof(User)*MAX_LINE);
    Review *reviews = malloc(sizeof(Review)*MAX_LINE);
//i do the allocation of memory.

    FILE *files;
    files = fopen(argv[1],"r"); //opening the file

    if(files == NULL)
    {
     printf("Failed to open file");//in case of fail to open the file
     exit(1);
    }
    
if(strcmp(argv[1], "reviews.csv") == 0)
     { 
      while (fgets(buffer2,COUNT,files))//trying to pass from the file to the struct
      {
        reviews[i].id = strdup(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i].user_id =strdup(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i].business_id =srdup(strsep(buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i].stars = atof(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i].useful = atoi(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i].funny = atoi(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
        reviews[i++].cool = atoi(strsep(&buffer2,";"));
      }
  
    
      for(int j=0; j < i-1; j++)//testing if the data was well copied.
      {
       printf("%s", reviews[j].id); //param
       printf("%s", reviews[j].user_id); //param
       printf("%s", reviews[j].business_id); //param
       printf("%f", reviews[j].stars);  //param
       printf("%d", reviews[j].useful); //param
       printf("%d", reviews[j].funny);
       printf("%d", reviews[j].cool);
       printf("\n");
      }
    }

  fclose(files); // When i don't need the file i close it
  free(user);//I give free to the memory
  free(reviews);// Same thing
  free(buffer2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `srdup()`? Was this the actual code copy/pasted without introducing errors? Note that you are not checking the return value of  `strsep()`. Never trust that data is formatted as expected (or is complete). If it returns `NULL` you'll be dereferencing that `NULL` pointer - seg fault. While you are at it, make a check that `i < MAX_LINE`.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation faults occurs only incase there are some memory issues. The code above uses command line argument as well as dynamic allocation through malloc.
I suggest remove the command line arguments from main() to make the code looks simpler. The problem here related to memory so try to specify memory statically not dynamically using malloc(),calloc() etc.